# Why does apache log requests to GET http://www.google.com with code 200?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, http, httpd, vulnerabilities

I was recently asked 'What causes a line like this in our access.log?'

59.56.109.181 - - [22/Feb/2010:16:03:35 -0800] "GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1" 200 295 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Win2000)"

My immediate answer is that's someone exploring something a little devious.

But:

- how? Speculation... a short perl or python script could easily connect and ask for a URL with an invalid host.
- Vulnerabilities?  What is someone looking for when they do this, what have they learned, and should we patch it?
- Do I need a tin-foil hat to keep them from reading my mind?
- And for me the real question: **Shouldn't that be a 404 response, not a 200!?**

This is on a standard LAMP server (Ubuntu).

Comment: First question: did you write your entire Apache configuration yourself? Is this a server you've inherited responsibility for?

Comment: Co-workers server. Conf mostly comes from default packaging in Ubuntu.  It will be a while if you want a conf file... I'm looking in my servers to see if it replicates...ah found some. Since its debian style the conf is split up -- what pieces do you need?

Comment: One server this replicates on is a standard VPS at linode.  The apache conf is set up for virtual hosting.  sites.enabled contains, among other things, a 000-default with a "VirtualHost *:80" declaration.  Could that be what lets in requests to http://www.google.com ?

Comment: @PP no, I didn't write /etc/apache2/* myself. And I was hoping rich Uncle would leave me his Lamborghini, but all I got was this fracking server full of pr0n that keeps emailing whitehouse.gov .  Actually a co-worker did ask me about seeing this on his server and I was looking for something better to say than "I've seen this too. The server won't explode, so who cares!?" After a few hacks get past, you start to care.

Comment: I only ask because there may be some rewrite rules in the configuration somewhere. I would expect that, with a clean install, you wouldn't see the kind of HTTP request you gave with a 200 response. However Apache is extremely configurable and could well re-write such a URL into an acceptable form.

Comment: @PP good point on rewrite, I don't tend to use those and so had forgotten about that.  +1.  I suspect the virtualhost * + human nature. Still don't know all the answers though.

Comment: If you want codegolf - `printf 'GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n'|nc yourserver.com 80`

Comment: +1 nc looks cool as replacement for telnet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you want to read http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ProxyAbuse

specially this point: "My server is properly configured not to proxy, so why is Apache returning a 200 (Success) status code?", it asks your question "Shouldn't that be a 404 response, not a 200!?"

If apache conf is ok, its just sending root page. It's the reason because you get a status code is 200.

Answer (score 4):

I think this would happen if someone tried to use the server as a proxy. That would make the http://... URL "normal" (as opposed to just the path portion that you would expect from a regular server request.)

As for the 200 status code, that... err.. well, my server does that too. It seems to ignore the http://hostname portion and returns the result from the local server using the remaining path. You'll probably have to dig through the RFCs to figure out why that makes sense; I don't know the answer offhand.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not using your server as a proxy,
these likely are common attempts of [proxy abuse](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/ProxyAbuse) regularly seen on internet facing web servers.

The requests that received a status code of 200 probably returned your index page.
You can check this using [`telnet`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/telnet) or [`curl`](https://curl.se/).

Suppose that:

- your sever name is `site.example.org`;
- third parties are trying to connect to `news.example.net` and `search.example.com`;
- your `/index.html` file contains:

  ```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head><title>It works!</title></head>
    <body><h1>It works!</h1></body>
    </html>
  ```

Using **[curl](https://curl.se/)**,
you can reconstruct the requests you received like so:

```
$ curl site.example.org --request-target http://news.example.net/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>It works!</title></head>
<body><h1>It works!</h1></body>
</html>
```

Using **[telnet](https://linux.die.net/man/1/telnet)**,
you can reconstruct the requests you received like so:

```
$ telnet site.example.org 80
> GET http://news.example.com/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: news.example.com
>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Content-Type: text/html
...

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>It works!</title></head>
<body><h1>It works!</h1></body>
</html>
```

If you receive your `index.html` as a result, that means your server
is not configured as a proxy and you should not worry about these requests.

If you actually receive the contents of `news.example.com` or `news.example.net`
your web server is configured as a proxy.
You can deactivate this by commenting any `proxy on;` lines on your Nginx configs
or by disabling `mod_proxy` on your Apache configs.

Some interesting references about this:

- [Proxy Abuse on Apache's wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/httpd/ProxyAbuse)
- [Unusal GET requests in my nodejs journal - has my nginx/node been hacked?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/235354/unusal-get-requests-in-my-nodejs-journal-has-my-nginx-node-been-hacked)
- [Server getting probed: why can I see successful GET requests to other sites?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/202012/server-getting-probed-why-can-i-see-successful-get-requests-to-other-sites)