# Prevent my website from being displayed under foreign domains

Tags: nginx, security

I'm not sure what's happening but i've just found, that someone has registered domain name `*-auth.ga` that displays my website. I'm not sure how can i block that kind of issue, i don't just want to ban each domain directly. I'm looking for a more general solution.

This website is not using iframe, **my nginx host has a domain name specified (dns of that fake domain is not pointing to my server so it's not an issue actually i think)**, i'm also forcing SSL connection but this fake domain uses ssl as well (`https://*-auth.ga`) so this all seems really misterious. Anyway, even with the basic protection settings mentioned above, i'm still able to reach my website under fake domain and i can see the access logs on my server (so it's not any kind of a mirror nor anything like that)

How can i prevent such behaviour in nginx/app? can anyone explain me what's that, why someone is doing it and why/if it can be dangerous in any way? I'm not even sure how to google for that nor what tags to use in here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the requests for the fake domain all coming from the same IP address (e.g. not the one you use when accessing it)?

Comment: Nope, they are coming from the different address. So i think that website is just a kind of a proxy

Comment: Yes, that's what I was getting at. Dealing with this in a general way is difficult and as a first step I would simply block the offending IP and see if this fixes the problem before investing time in more involved attempts to prevent this.

Comment: Yeah that's what i'm gonna do :) Anyway, is there any name for such thing? To let me google it up and read more about it?

Comment: Have a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/662262/apache-accepting-requests-to-other-servers/662356#662356 - it's about apache, but nginx functions the same way.